# Inject Bean that uses @Named with value

Tags: jsf, cdi, inject

how can I Inject a Bean, that uses a `@Named` annotation along with a value?

```
@Named
public class LanguageService{
   ...
} 

public class SomeOtherBean{

    @Inject
    private LanguageService languageService
}
```

works without Problem - but how to inject, if i'm using:

```
@Named("lang")
public class LanguageService{
   ...
}
```

`@Inject` can't have a value as `@ManagedProperty` does. (But I wan't to stay with CDI)

Edit:
I noticed that it doesn't matter how the bean is named. My Fault that leads to an NPE was simple that i created `SomeOtherBean` manually, and ofc. no Injection was done. My fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDI selects injectable beans by type (and qualifiers) and not by the annotation parameter. The name is used to address a CDI bean from views, e.g. facelets.